# Binary tree traversal in scala

Tags: scala, binary-tree

given bin tree defn :

```
// a binary tree node
 case class Node( var data:(Int), 
     left:Option[Node],
     right:Option[Node] 
       )
```

I need to get the in order tree traversal of the binary tree. 
for eg:

```
val testtree = Node( (3),
                     None,
                     Some(Node( (5),
                                Some(Node( (1),
                                     None,
                                     None )),
                             Some(Node( (9),
                                      None,
                                      Some(Node( (15), 
                                                 None,
                                                 None )) ))  ))  )
```

inorder for this tree shd be : 3,5,1,9,15

Code which I tried:

```
 def inOrder(t: Node): Unit ={  
   def print(data:Int,t:Option[Node]):Unit={
      if(t!=None)
                    {
                        print(data,t.left)
            Console.print(data)
            print(data,t.right)
        }      
   }
   print(t.data,t)  
 }
```

But its not working out. Can someone help me out.

Full code :

```
    case class Node( var data:(Int), 
         left:Option[Node],
         right:Option[Node] 
           )

object Ch15 {

  def main( args:Array[String] ) = {
   val tree =Node( (3), None,Some(Node( (5), Some(Node( (1), None, None )), Some(Node( (9), None,Some(Node( (15), None, None )) )) )) )    
   inOrder( tree ) 
  }

  def inOrder(t: Node): Unit ={  
   def print(data:Int,t:Option[Node]):Unit={
      if(t!=None)
      {
            print(data,t.left)
            Console.print(data)
            print(data,t.right)
        }      
   }
   print(t.data,t)  
 }

}
```

Comment: What does "it's not working out" mean? What's not happening the way you expect?

Comment: I suspect it means "not compiling".

Comment: yep. there are multiple errors. As I am new to scala, looking for some help frm people out here. Either fixing my method defn or giving your own defn of inOrder() would be great. Only constraint is that the Node defn shouldnt change.

Comment: Please post complete code that you expect to compile. And say what you've tried so far.

Comment: Still no details on the errors or what you've tried? This isn't a site for getting people to do your assignments. Helping you with a specific issue is one thing, fixing all the problems without you doing your part is not.

Comment: But as a starter-for-10, `t.left` won't work. `t` is not a `Node`, but an `Option[Node]`

Comment: Yes, I am confused with the same. How can I make a recursive call to print() by passing in the left Node of the current node, t? I am getting an error like 'value left is not a member of Option[Node].

Comment: Only de defn of Node was given to me as ques. I wrote the inOrder() defn my own and have given it here for review. As I told you i couldn't get it working due to few errors. Is there any fundamental mistake which I am making so that I can fix it myself?

Comment: Exactly. So you need to get the Node out of Option[Node]. Hint#2: look at what t.map{...} does when t is None and when t is Some(n). Also, I think you'd get less confused if you didn't use `t`for both Node and Option=[Node] at different points...

Comment: thnx paul. I guess I got it. t.left.get should fix it rite. Will try it out.

Comment: t.left.get would work - as long as t isn't None. So, do look at t.map{...}, it makes things very convenient.

Answer (score 4):

```
case class Branch(node: Int, left: Option[Branch] = None, right: Option[Branch] = None)

object TreeTraverse extends App {
  val branch = Branch(1, Some(Branch(2, Some(Branch(4)), Some(Branch(5)))), Some(Branch(3, Some(Branch(6)), Some(Branch(7)))))

  def preOrder(branch: Branch): Unit = {
    print(branch.node)
    if (branch.left.isDefined) preOrder(branch.left.get)
    if (branch.right.isDefined) preOrder(branch.right.get)
  }

  def inOrder(branch: Branch): Unit = {
    if (branch.left.isDefined) inOrder(branch.left.get)
    print(branch.node)
    if (branch.right.isDefined) inOrder(branch.right.get)
  }

  def postOrder(branch: Branch): Unit = {
    if (branch.left.isDefined) postOrder(branch.left.get)
    if (branch.right.isDefined) postOrder(branch.right.get)
    print(branch.node)
  }

  println("  -> PreOrder" + preOrder(branch))
  println("  -> InOrder " + inOrder(branch))
  println("  -> PostOrder " + postOrder(branch))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think the in-order traversal would result in 3,1,5,9,15 instead of OP's 3,5,1,9,15.
And, sorry I could not get your code to compile as is. Also, as Paul suggested, you are confusing the "t"s.

Here is my take on the implementation:

```
object Ch15 {
  def main( args:Array[String] ) = {
   val tree =Node( (3), None,Some(Node( (5), Some(Node( (1), None, None )), Some(Node( (9), None,Some(Node( (15), None, None )) )) )) )    
   inOrder( tree ) 
  }

  def inOrder(t: Node): Unit ={  
    def printNode(node:Option[Node]):Unit={
      node match {
        case Some(aliveNode) => {
          printNode(aliveNode.left)
          Console.print(aliveNode.data + ", ")
          printNode(aliveNode.right)
        }
        case None => {}
      }
    }
    printNode(Option(t))  
  }
}
```